# Compiling mp4v2 on Mac OS X

Tags: c++, xcode, stl, macos, g++

Anybody can help me with compiling mp4v2 on Mac OS X?  I've tried configuring and compiling as per the instructions but I got a lot of errors originating from the C++ headers.  The configure command was `./configure --enable-ub` followed by plain `make` at the Terminal.

From the looks of the error messages, it seems that a number of header files are missing from my installation.  The problem is that I **did not remove** any header files and installed Xcode as-is from the installer DMG.

It seems that these files are required but not present in my from my Xcode installation:

- `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/c++config.h`
- `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/c++locale.h`
- `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/c++io.h`
- `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/ghtr.h`
- `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/atomic_word.h`
- (and then some)

They are all included by the STL C++ headers provided by the system (all of the files that references to these missing files are in `/user/include/c++/4.2.1`.

Anybody can help tell me where do I get these "missing" header files?

Here are the version details of each software involved:

- Snow Leopard 10.6.4
- Xcode 3.2.3 (the one that came with iOS SDK 4.0)
- MP4v2 1.9.1
- i686-apple-darwin10-g++-4.2.1 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)

The following are some excerpts of the error messages:

```
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -arch ppc -arch ppc64 -I./include -I./include -I. -I.  -Wall -Wformat -g -O2 -fvisibility=hidden  -c libplatform/impl.h -o libplatform/impl.h.gch/static
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ios:43,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/istream:44,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/fstream:45,
                 from ./libplatform/platform_base.h:6,
                 from ./libplatform/platform_posix.h:31,
                 from ./libplatform/platform.h:24,
                 from libplatform/impl.h:6:
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/iosfwd:44:28: error: bits/c++config.h: No such file or directory
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/iosfwd:45:29: error: bits/c++locale.h: No such file or directory
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/iosfwd:46:25: error: bits/c++io.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/ios_base.h:45,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ios:48,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/istream:44,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/fstream:45,
                 from ./libplatform/platform_base.h:6,
                 from ./libplatform/platform_posix.h:31,
                 from ./libplatform/platform.h:24,
                 from libplatform/impl.h:6:
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ext/atomicity.h:39:23: error: bits/gthr.h: No such file or directory
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ext/atomicity.h:40:30: error: bits/atomic_word.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/memory:54,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/string:48,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/locale_classes.h:47,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/ios_base.h:47,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ios:48,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/istream:44,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/fstream:45,
                 from ./libplatform/platform_base.h:6,
                 from ./libplatform/platform_posix.h:31,
                 from ./libplatform/platform.h:24,
                 from libplatform/impl.h:6:
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you get this from MacPorts or are you trying to do it directly from the original source code ? If the latter then try the former.

Comment: From the original source code.  The end-goal is to embed the library in my Leopard app tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it right:

```
./configure --disable-gch --enable-ub=ppc,i386,x86_64
```

Refer to [mp4v2 issue 58](http://code.google.com/p/mp4v2/issues/detail?id=58).

Furthermore there are additional steps required when [you use Snow Leopard to build but you also want mp4v2 to be usable under Leopard](http://cubic-m.blogspot.com/2010/06/building-mp4v2-library-for-leopard.html).

Thanks